# Suckless's simple terminal how to configure alt gr and single keystroke for tilde

Tags: terminal, x-st

In Suckless's simple terminal (st) I can type the tilde `~` by pressing the keys `alt gr` and `4`. But with `alt gr` and the key to the right of the `ñ` key, I have to press twice this last key, I want to use `alt gr` and a single keystroke of the key to the right of the `ñ` key.

I can do it on other terminals and applications, for example xfce4-terminal, Firefox...

Details:

- Keyboard: Spanish, example: https://assets.ltkcontent.com/images/spanish-keyboard-yd.jpg.
- Operating system: Arch Linux
- Window manager: i3wm
- `localectl status` command output:

```
    System Locale: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
        VC Keymap: es
        X11 Layout: es
```

I don't know If I have to modify the st config files.

Thank you for your help.